# Debian Apache не правильно работает с под доменом

Tags: linux, debian, apache2, vpn

**test.site.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    ServerName test.site.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/test/>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**site.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site.com
    ServerName site.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/site.com/>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Проблема**: при переходи в браузере по урл http://site.com все нормально, но при попытке перехода на суб домен http://test.site.com меня кидает на основной сайт.

**Вопрос**: Где я накосячил? Спасибо

Comment: Ответ на основании имеющихся данных: где-то в другом месте.

Comment: Может быть в любом месте, хоть в коде, хоть в `.htaccess` хоть в кэше браузера. Проверять надо не в браузере, а например через `curl` - тогда можно говорить о проблеме.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй в config субдомена добавить `ServerAlias www.subdomain.test.com`

Comment: Пробовал , нечего не меняется